# Why is this COBOL code failing to compile?

Tags: compilation, cobol, mainframe

I'm trying to get this code to compile and I continue to get the same error at the same location. I will show the error I'm getting when I compile it along with the code where it's erroring out.

Error:

```
UPDATE-TOTALS.
  000202                    ADD WS-T-EXTENDED-PRICE TO WS-TOTALS (1:13)                           99 98
 
==000202==> IGYPA3074-S "WS-TOTALS (ALPHANUMERIC REFERENCE MODIFIED ITEM)" was not numeric, but
                        was a sender in an arithmetic expression.  The statement was discarded.
 
  000203                    ADD WS-T-NET-PRICE TO WS-TOTALS (14:13)                               101 98
 
==000203==> IGYPA3074-S "WS-TOTALS (ALPHANUMERIC REFERENCE MODIFIED ITEM)" was not numeric, but
                        was a sender in an arithmetic expression.  The statement was discarded.
 
  000204                    ADD WS-T-TRANSPORTATION TO WS-TOTALS (27:13)                          103 98
 
==000204==> IGYPA3074-S "WS-TOTALS (ALPHANUMERIC REFERENCE MODIFIED ITEM)" was not numeric, but
                        was a sender in an arithmetic expression.  The statement was discarded.
 
  000205                    ADD WS-T-DISCOUNT-AMOUNT TO WS-TOTALS (40:13).                        105 98
 
==000205==> IGYPA3074-S "WS-TOTALS (ALPHANUMERIC REFERENCE MODIFIED ITEM)" was not numeric, but
                        was a sender in an arithmetic expression.  The statement was discarded.
```

Code:

```
//where i declared it
01  WS-TOTALS.
           05  WS-T-EXTENDED-PRICE              PIC S9(11)V99
                VALUE 0.
           05  WS-T-NET-PRICE                   PIC S9(11)V99
                VALUE 0.
           05  WS-T-TRANSPORTATION              PIC S9(11)V99
                VALUE 0.
           05  WS-T-DISCOUNT-AMOUNT             PIC S9(11)V99
                VALUE 0.
//rest of my code
//error where its happening
       UPDATE-TOTALS.
           ADD WS-T-EXTENDED-PRICE TO WS-TOTALS (1:13)
           ADD WS-T-NET-PRICE TO WS-TOTALS (14:13)
           ADD WS-T-TRANSPORTATION TO WS-TOTALS (27:13)
           ADD WS-T-DISCOUNT-AMOUNT TO WS-TOTALS (40:13).
```

Comment: The error message explains what's wrong.  `WS-TOTALS (1:13)` is alphanumeric and can't be the object of an ADD instruction.  Substitute `WS-T-EXTENDED-PRICE`.  The other errors are similar.

Comment: Part of the problem was already mentioned in one of the comments, you were using reference modification as part of an ADD statement.

But things don't quite seem right here.  The WS-TOTALS data item is a group.  And you are trying to add each member of that group to itself, judging by the byte positions mentioned in the reference modifications.

Do you really want to do something like ADD WS-EXTENDED-PRICE TO WS-T-EXTENDED-PRICE, and so on, adding some other field to the total extended price?